# Meaning of 'stark'

Tags: dictionaries

What is the meaning of *stark*?

I have got from Cambridge dictionary: **empty, simple or obvious, especially without decoration or anything which is not necessary; severe or extreme**

*Simple* and *severe* are two opposite words.

So how they give us same meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP misunderstands the relevant meaning of...

> [simple](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/simple) *- not ornate or luxurious; unadorned:* a simple gown.

...and/or...

> [severe](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/severe) *- rigidly restrained in style, taste, manner, etc.; **simple, plain,** or austere.*

The fact that both these words have other meaning and connotations is beside the point. But it's worth noting that *stark* (which ultimately derives from [strong](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stark)) often simply means *completely*, or *extremely*...

> *stark naked*
>    *stark raving mad*
>    etc., etc.

It can also replace adjectival forms such as *complete* (e.g. - *"This is in stark contrast to that"*).

Comment: In March 2011, the Russian security service sent a stark warning to the F.B.I., reporting that Tamerlan Tsarnaev was “a follower of radical Islam”
what would be the meaning of this?

Comment: @Laser, since I'm a learner, can you explain how is Tsarnaev's story, also admitting it is true, related to the English language and, especially, to FF's answer?

Comment: http://www.nytimes.com/2013/04/26/us/russia-told-us-bomb-suspect-was-radical-islamist.html?ref=us&_r=0
check the link

Comment: @Laser, ah, I see. I think 'stark' there means that the message was written using a minimal number of words, those strictly needed.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: Actually, I think the key sense in a ***stark** warning* is more that of being *extremely blunt. That's *sheer, absolute, unqualified* from OED, and [unpleasantly clear and obvious](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/stark_1) from cambridge dictionaries. The word *stark* has a long history, including many (related) senses, not all of which are current or common today.

Comment: @Laser-boy: Your question would have been a much better one had you included the dictionary research (which was excellent, by the way) *and* the sentence from the Times article (which I assume prompted the question.

Comment: @J.R.: I'm assuming OP's problem primarily concerns the fact that he couldn't reconcile *stark=simple* with *stark=severe*. But even given the full context of [sends a stark message](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sends+a+stark%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example, I think it would usually be somewhat subjective as to which ***exact*** nuance was intended. Per OED, it could be *unyielding, stern, inflexible* in an old text (OED says that's an obsolete sense). Or *violent/stern, harsh, severe*, or *stout, powerful*, or *sheer, absolute, unqualified*, etc., etc.